# Unable to run scala.js on PhantomJSEnv, requiresDOM setting is forced to false

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js

I'd like to use websockets :

```
import org.scalajs.dom
import scala.scalajs.js.JSApp
import org.scalajs.dom.{CloseEvent, ErrorEvent, Event, MessageEvent}

object ExampleJS extends JSApp {

  def main(): Unit = {
    val data = ""

    val ws = new dom.WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8182")
 // val ws = new dom.WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8182, "whatever")

    ws.onmessage = (x: MessageEvent) => Console.println(x.data.toString)
    ws.onopen = (x: Event) => {}
    ws.onerror = (x: ErrorEvent) => Console.println("some error has occurred " + x.message)
    ws.onclose = (x: CloseEvent) => {}

    ws.send(data)
  }

}
```

But I'm still getting error like this :

```
[error] /home/lisak/src/viagraphs/scalajs-gremlin-client/js/target/scala-2.11/js-fastopt.js:1221
[error]   var ws = new ScalaJS.g["WebSocket"]("ws://127.0.0.1:8081");
[error]            ^
[error] TypeError: undefined is not a function
[error]     at ScalaJS.c.Lcom_viagraphs_ExampleJS$.main__V (/home/lisak/src/viagraphs/scalajs-gremlin-client/js/target/scala-2.11/js-fastopt.js:1221:12)
[error]     at ScalaJS.c.Lcom_viagraphs_ExampleJS$.$$js$exported$meth$main__O (/home/lisak/src/viagraphs/scalajs-gremlin-client/js/target/scala-2.11/js-fastopt.js:1243:16)
[error]     at ScalaJS.c.Lcom_viagraphs_ExampleJS$.main (/home/lisak/src/viagraphs/scalajs-gremlin-client/js/target/scala-2.11/js-fastopt.js:1246:15)
[error]     at [stdin]:17:91
[error]     at Object.<anonymous> ([stdin]-wrapper:6:22)
[error]     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
[error]     at evalScript (node.js:532:25)
[error]     at Socket.<anonymous> (node.js:154:11)
[error]     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
[error]     at _stream_readable.js:920:16

> last fastOptStage::run
[info] Running com.viagraphs.ExampleJS
[debug] with JSEnv of type class scala.scalajs.sbtplugin.env.nodejs.NodeJSEnv
[debug] with classpath of type class scala.scalajs.tools.classpath.CompleteCIClasspath$SimpleCompleteCIClasspath
[error] 
[error] /home/lisak/src/viagraphs/scalajs-gremlin-client/js/target/scala-2.11/js-fastopt.js:1221
[error]   var ws = new ScalaJS.g["WebSocket"]("ws://127.0.0.1:8081");
[error]            ^
[error] TypeError: undefined is not a function
[error]     at ScalaJS.c.Lcom_viagraphs_ExampleJS$.main__V (/home/lisak/src/viagraphs/scalajs-gremlin-client/js/target/scala-2.11/js-fastopt.js:1221:12)
[error]     at ScalaJS.c.Lcom_viagraphs_ExampleJS$.$$js$exported$meth$main__O (/home/lisak/src/viagraphs/scalajs-gremlin-client/js/target/scala-2.11/js-fastopt.js:1243:16)
[error]     at ScalaJS.c.Lcom_viagraphs_ExampleJS$.main (/home/lisak/src/viagraphs/scalajs-gremlin-client/js/target/scala-2.11/js-fastopt.js:1246:15)
[error]     at [stdin]:17:91
[error]     at Object.<anonymous> ([stdin]-wrapper:6:22)
[error]     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
[error]     at evalScript (node.js:532:25)
[error]     at Socket.<anonymous> (node.js:154:11)
[error]     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
[error]     at _stream_readable.js:920:16
java.lang.RuntimeException: node.js exited with code 8
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
        at scala.scalajs.sbtplugin.env.ExternalJSEnv.runJS(ExternalJSEnv.scala:65)
        at scala.scalajs.sbtplugin.env.nodejs.NodeJSEnv.scala$scalajs$sbtplugin$env$nodejs$NodeJSEnv$$super$runJS(NodeJSEnv.scala:76)
        at scala.scalajs.sbtplugin.env.nodejs.NodeJSEnv$$anonfun$runJS$1.apply$mcV$sp(NodeJSEnv.scala:76)
        at scala.scalajs.sbtplugin.env.nodejs.NodeJSEnv$$anonfun$runJS$1.apply(NodeJSEnv.scala:76)
        at scala.scalajs.sbtplugin.env.nodejs.NodeJSEnv$$anonfun$runJS$1.apply(NodeJSEnv.scala:76)
        at scala.scalajs.sbtplugin.env.nodejs.NodeJSEnv$$anonfun$withLibCache$1.apply(NodeJSEnv.scala:43)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at scala.scalajs.sbtplugin.env.nodejs.NodeJSEnv.withLibCache(NodeJSEnv.scala:42)
        at scala.scalajs.sbtplugin.env.nodejs.NodeJSEnv.runJS(NodeJSEnv.scala:76)
        at scala.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal$.scala$scalajs$sbtplugin$ScalaJSPluginInternal$$jsRun(ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala:356)
        at scala.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal$$anonfun$48$$anonfun$apply$18$$anonfun$apply$19.apply(ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala:420)
        at scala.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal$$anonfun$48$$anonfun$apply$18$$anonfun$apply$19.apply(ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala:414)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (js/compile:fastOptStage::run) node.js exited with code 8
```

I tried RhinoJSEnv and NodeJSEnv, both end with an error like this. I can't run it on PhantomJSEnv, I have it installed on linux, it is on PATH and working. The problem is that `requiresDOM` setting is always `false` even though I explicitly set it to `true` thuse PhantomJSEnv is never chosen as a runtime :

```
  override lazy val settings =
    super.settings ++ Seq(
      version := "0.0.1",
      scalaVersion := "2.11.2",
      resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal,
      offline := true
    )

  lazy val js = project.in(file("js")).settings(
    Seq(
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.7-SNAPSHOT",
        "com.lihaoyi" %%% "utest" % "0.2.0" % "test"
      ),
      test in Test := (test in (Test, fastOptStage)).value,
      testFrameworks += new TestFramework("utest.runner.JvmFramework"),
      requiresDOM := true
    ) ++ Plugin.internal.utestJsSettings ++ scalaJSSettings:_*
  )
```

Comment: What happens if you try to `fastOptStage::run` with PhantomJS? The TypeError? Could you also try running this in a browser?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce any unexpected behavior. Please give more details. Also have a look here: https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/865 (fixed in 0.5.3 though).

Comment: The primary problem is, that even though I fulfilled the conditions specified in documentation for `fastOptStage::run` to use PhantomJS, it just uses Node.js, instead of PhantomJS. You are telling me that if you set up project with this Build setup and code, it works ?

Comment: I updated the stack trace that goes from fastOptStage::run (on Node.js)

Comment: I forgot to mention, chrome runs it fine when I put it in html page... It just that it doesn't work in Rhino, Node.js and I've got a feeling it'd run with PhantomJS, but I can't make it run the script to try if it works or not... The app I'm doing has no UI, so there is really no need for html and browser, so I wanted to use Rhino, Node or PhantomJS

Comment: I've got the secondary reason why PhantomJS is not used as JSEnv. `> show requiresDOM` is `false` although I don't know why, I set it to true, something in the `js` project must override it to false. I tried to eliminate all settings except for `scalaJSSettings:_*` and the `requiresDOM` is still forced to `false`

Comment: Is it possible that one of those commits in https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/787 is forcing requiresDOM to false no matter what settings you explicitly set in the project ? I think it might be it...90%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your build definition to the following:

```
lazy val js = project.in(file("js"))
  .settings(scalaJSSettings: _*)
  .settings(Plugin.internal.utestJsSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.7-SNAPSHOT",
      "com.lihaoyi" %%% "utest" % "0.2.0" % "test"
    ),
    test in Test := (test in (Test, fastOptStage)).value,
    testFrameworks += new TestFramework("utest.runner.JvmFramework"),
    requiresDOM := true
  )
```

Note the change of order (using `.settings` multiple times doesn't change anything, its just cleaner IMHO). If you put your project specific settings first,  and then the Scala.js settings. The defaults in `scalaJSSettings` will override your settings and `requiresDOM` will be false.

Comment: It works!:-) I'm sure that I tried to change the order and it had no effect, but now it does and it uses PhantomJS finally, so it probably didn't reloaded before or something... Although the websockets don't work on PhanotomJS too - just nothing happens, even if I keep it busy at the end so that the runtime wouldn't kill it before completing the connection...

Comment: That, unfortunately is a PhantomJS issue. You know that they support hixie-76 websockets only, according to this: http://phantomjs.org/inter-process-communication.html

Comment: I see, and what about Node and Rhino ? It is crashing with the error I pasted to the my question. How would you go about developing websocket  client that has no UI on scalajs? Should I go via html ?